# How can I add object in array as value length?

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to know how i can add object in array length.

I asked this question before,
and I got the hint at the moment but i can't still figure it out how to do it ,
so here is my piece code :

```js
const [data, setdata] = useState([
    { x: 1, y: 2 },
    { x: 1, y: 2 },
    { x: 1, y: 2 },
  ]);
  
  
  const newData = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const updateX = () => {
  setdata((data) => data.map((d, i) => ({ ...d, x: newData[i] })));
};


/////result ///


    { x: 3, y: 2 },
    { x: 4, y: 2 },
    { x: 5, y: 2 },




/// what i want ///


    { x: 3, y: 2 },
    { x: 4, y: 2 },
    { x: 5, y: 2 },
    { x: 6, y: 2 },
    { x: 7, y: 2 },
    { x: 8, y: 2 },
    { x: 9, y: 2 },
```

Comment: Remove the word "const"

Comment: @AbdullahArshad How will that solve the problem?

Comment: Const means that the object will be unchangable. You cannot change a const variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update like this:

```
const updateX = () => {
  setdata(newData.map((item, i) => ({ x: item, y: data[i] ?? 2 })));
};
```

Comment: Really good to see you again Sir !  Oh right !!!! Thank you so much !!!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are mapping over `data` which only has 3 elements. Therefore, the final result will only have 3 elements.

To create a new array from `newData`, then you must use `newData.map()` instead of `data.map()`. The simplest way would be to do it directly:

```
newData.map(item => {x: item, y: 2})
```